# request json from html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am unable to request JSON from HTML using request.

I am using the request package from npm.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MySite!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h2>
        its ya boi 
      </h2>
      <button onclick=ree>workkkkk</button>
      <script>
    const request = require('request')
    function ree() {
    request('https://api-quiz.hype.space/shows/now',(error,response,body) => { //requests data from the hq trivia api
    //bodys = JSON.parse(body)
    //document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = (bodys.nextShowPrize)
    //console.log(`Next game: ${body.nextShowTime}`)
    alert(body)
    })}
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what way is this code failing?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?  Is there anything on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  When you step through in the browser's script debugger, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fetch`.

```js
fetch('https://api-quiz.hype.space/shows/now')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: how could i make it replace the text with the json

Comment: @SkrtOnDiscord which text exactly?